# How to append data on a file in win32

Tags: file, winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

I've searched to do this but I can't find what am I doing incorrectly.I'm trying to make this function appends data every time it's called but it always do it once. If the file doesn't exist it creates a new one and write on file for ONLY once if the file exist it does nothing (or maybe overwrite)

```
void WriteToFile (char data[],wchar_t filename[] )
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(data);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten ;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;


    hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)filename,            // name of the write
        GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing 
        0,                      // do not share
        NULL,                   // default security
        CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
        NULL);                  // no attr. template

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("CreateFile"));
        _tprintf(TEXT("Terminal failure: Unable to open file \"%s\" for write.\n"), filename);
        return;
    }


    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
    hFile,              // open file handle
    data,               // start of data to write
    dwBytesToWrite,     // number of bytes to write
    &dwBytesWritten,    // number of bytes that were written
    NULL);              // no overlapped structure

    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("WriteFile"));
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite)
        {
        // This is an error because a synchronous write that results in
        // success (WriteFile returns TRUE) should write all data as
        // requested. This would not necessarily be the case for
        // asynchronous writes.
        printf("Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n");
       }
       else
       {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Wrote %d bytes to %s successfully.\n"), dwBytesWritten, filename);
    }
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

And this is where I call the function in `WM_COMMAND`

```
//When a menu item selected execute this code
case IDM_FILE_SAVE:
        saveBool = true;
        char Str[] = "this is my own data";
        wchar_t filename[] = L"data.txt";
        WriteToFile(Str, filename);
        break;
```

Comment: Why not use the c++ standard library?

Comment: you need use *OPEN_ALWAYS* in *dwCreationDisposition* instead *CREATE_NEW*. and in *dwDesiredAccess* must be *FILE_APPEND_DATA* but not *GENERIC_WRITE*

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, that works well

Comment: read more here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> if the file exist it does nothing

As it should be.  Per the [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) documentation:

> CREATE_NEW
>   1
>   Creates a new file, **only if it does not already exist**.
>
> **If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80)**.
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, a new file is created.

For what you are attempting to do, use `OPEN_ALWAYS` instead:

> OPEN_ALWAYS
>   4
>   Opens a file, always.
>
> If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero.

You can use the `FILE_APPEND_DATA` access specifier to have `CreateFile()` automatically seek to the end of the file after creating/opening it (otherwise, you have to seek manually using `SetFilePointer/Ex()`) before you then write new data to the file.

Try this:

```
void WriteToFile (char *data, wchar_t *filename)
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = strlen(data);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten ;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

    hFile = CreateFileW(filename,  // name of the write
        FILE_APPEND_DATA,          // open for appending
        FILE_SHARE_READ,           // share for reading only
        NULL,                      // default security
        OPEN_ALWAYS,               // open existing file or create new file 
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,     // normal file
        NULL);                     // no attr. template

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("CreateFile"));
        wprintf(L"Terminal failure: Unable to create/open file \"%s\" for writing.\n", filename);
        return;
    }

    while (dwBytesToWrite > 0)
    {
        bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
            hFile,              // open file handle
            data,               // start of data to write
            dwBytesToWrite,     // number of bytes to write
            &dwBytesWritten,    // number of bytes that were written
            NULL);              // no overlapped structure

        if (!bErrorFlag)
        {
            DisplayError(TEXT("WriteFile"));
            printf("Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
            break;
        }

        wprintf(L"Wrote %u bytes to \"%s\" successfully.\n", dwBytesWritten, filename);

        data += dwBytesWritten;
        dwBytesToWrite -= dwBytesWritten;
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the location for writing, then that may overwrite the first part.
The [CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) documentation says for the `CREATE_NEW` flag:

> Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist. If the
> specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is
> set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80).

The flag `OPEN_ALWAYS` flag is fit your needs. It also says:

> Opens a file, always. If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and
> the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable
> location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set
> to zero.

The [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) documentation says:

> [in, out, optional] lpOverlapped
>
> ...
>
> To write to the end of file, specify both the Offset and OffsetHigh
> members of the OVERLAPPED structure as 0xFFFFFFFF. This is
> functionally equivalent to previously calling the CreateFile function
> to open hFile using FILE_APPEND_DATA access.

Then you don't need to use `FILE_APPEND_DATA` flag, `SetFilePointer`, or `SetFilePointerEx` function to set the pointer to the end.

This is an example:

```
    LPCWSTR fileName=L"D:\foo\bar.txt";
    LPCWSTR buffer=L"dummy text";
    HANDLE fileHandle=CreateFileW(fileName,
                                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                  NULL,
                                  CREATE_ALWAYS,
                                  NULL,
                                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                  NULL);
    if (fileHandle==ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) CloseHandle(fileHandle);
    OVERLAPPED writeFlag{0};
    writeFlag.DUMMYUNIONNAME.DUMMYSTRUCTNAME.Offset=0xFFFFFFFF;
    writeFlag.DUMMYUNIONNAME.DUMMYSTRUCTNAME.OffsetHigh=0xFFFFFFFF;
    WriteFile(fileHandle,buffer,sizeof(buffer),&writeFlag);
    // do another things here
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
```

You can change the buffer to any buffer you need to write at the end of file, and the file name.

Also, there are the `SetEndOfFile` function, without the `OVERLAPPED` structure.

Example:

```
    LPCWSTR fileName=L"D:\foo\bar.txt";
    LPCWSTR buffer=L"dummy text";
    HANDLE fileHandle=CreateFileW(fileName,
                                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                  NULL,
                                  OPEN_ALWAYS,
                                  NULL,
                                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                  NULL);
    if (fileHandle==ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) CloseHandle(fileHandle);
    SetEndOfFile(fileHandle);
    if (GetLastError()==ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) CloseHandle(fileHandle);
    WriteFile(fileHandle,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    // do another things here
    CloseHandle(fileHandle);
```