# How can multiple processes append to a Windows Terminal Server Client file without overwriting?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, writefile, createfile, terminal-services

I want to run a program in multiple processes and have that program append records to the same file. The append works when running on a non-Windows Server to a local file. It is not working when the program is run on a Windows Server and writing to a file on a shared client drive using the Terminal Server Client syntax. For example, \tsclient\c\temp\myfile-append.txt. If I call CreateFile() with dwDesiredAccess set to GENERIC_WRITE, all data from process 1 gets overwritten, instead of appended to, by process 2. If I replace GENERIC_WRITE with FILE_APPEND_DATA, the file is created but gets ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when calling WriteFile().

When I run on a Windows Server I see a WriteFile() error with FILE_APPEND_DATA:

```
process 1:
Running on a Windows Server and Terminal Services are enabled
CreateFile: \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-write.txt
WriteFile: TEST-6620
WriteFile: TEST-6620
WriteFile: TEST-6620
WriteFile: TEST-6620
**CreateFile: \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-append.txt
WriteFile: TEST-6620
WriteFile returned ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER errno:87**
Press return to exit...

process 2:
Running on a Windows Server and Terminal Services are enabled
CreateFile: \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-write.txt
WriteFile: TEST-9020
WriteFile: TEST-9020
WriteFile: TEST-9020
WriteFile: TEST-9020
**CreateFile: \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-append.txt
WriteFile: TEST-9020
WriteFile returned ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER errno:87**
Press return to exit...
```

myfile-append was created but is empty because of the error.
myfile-write has the expected last 4 records written from process 2:

```
TEST-4424
TEST-4424
TEST-4424
TEST-4424
```

When I run on a non-Windows Server, there are no errors:

```
process 1
Terminal Services are not enabled so using local files
CreateFile: myfile-write.txt
WriteFile: TEST-8320
WriteFile: TEST-8320
WriteFile: TEST-8320
WriteFile: TEST-8320
CreateFile: myfile-append.txt
WriteFile: TEST-8320
WriteFile: TEST-8320
WriteFile: TEST-8320
WriteFile: TEST-8320
Press return to exit...

process 2
Terminal Services are not enabled so using local files
CreateFile: myfile-write.txt
WriteFile: TEST-11992
WriteFile: TEST-11992
WriteFile: TEST-11992
WriteFile: TEST-11992
CreateFile: myfile-append.txt
WriteFile: TEST-11992
WriteFile: TEST-11992
WriteFile: TEST-11992
WriteFile: TEST-11992
Press return to exit...
```

myfile-append correctly has 8 records, 4 from each process:

```
TEST-24820
TEST-16324
TEST-24820
TEST-16324
TEST-24820
TEST-16324
TEST-24820
TEST-16324
```

myfile-write has the expected last 4 records written from process 2:

```
TEST-16324
TEST-16324
TEST-16324
TEST-16324
```

Does anyone know how I can get this program to run in multiple processes and have that program append records to the same file when the program is run on a Windows Server writing to a file on a shared client drive using the Terminal Server Client syntax?

**Windows batch script to run ConsoleApplication1.cpp in multiple processes**

```
@echo off

del \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-append.txt
del \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-write.txt

echo Starting process 1
START "process 1" ConsoleApplication1.exe

timeout /t 1

echo Starting process 2
START "process 2" ConsoleApplication1.exe

echo Press return after both processes have finished...
timeout /t -1

echo myfile-append file, should have 8 records, 4 from each process:
type \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-append.txt

echo myfile-write file, should have last 4 records written from process 2:
type \\tsclient\c\temp\myfile-write.txt
```

**ConsoleApplication1.cpp**

```
#define COUNT 4
#define SLEEP 2000
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <errhandlingapi.h>

wchar_t filename_local_write[512] = L"myfile-write.txt";
wchar_t filename_local_append[512] = L"myfile-append.txt";
wchar_t filename_ts_write[512] = L"\\\\tsclient\\c\\temp\\myfile-write.txt";
wchar_t filename_ts_append[512] = L"\\\\tsclient\\c\\temp\\myfile-append.txt";
wchar_t* filename_write;
wchar_t* filename_append;

void* myExit(int exitVal);

int main()
{
    int ii;
    char buf[512];
    DWORD rval;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    HANDLE hFile = 0;
    DWORD pid;

    // See if Terminal Services are enabled
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osVersionInfo;
    ULONGLONG dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(0, VER_SUITENAME, VER_AND);
    ZeroMemory(&osVersionInfo, sizeof(osVersionInfo));
    osVersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osVersionInfo);
    osVersionInfo.wSuiteMask = VER_SUITE_TERMINAL;
    int tsEnabled = VerifyVersionInfo((POSVERSIONINFOEX)&osVersionInfo, VER_SUITENAME, dwlConditionMask);
    if (tsEnabled) {
        printf("Running on a Windows Server and Terminal Services are enabled\n");
        filename_write = filename_ts_write;
        filename_append = filename_ts_append;
    } else {
        printf("Terminal Services are not enabled so using local files\n");
        filename_write = filename_local_write;
        filename_append = filename_local_append;
    }

    // Use process id as part of the records written so we
    // know what process the records were written from.
    pid = GetCurrentProcessId();

    // Create a file using GENERIC_WRITE

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    printf("CreateFile: %ws\n", filename_write);
    hFile = CreateFileW(
        filename_write,                     // lpFileName
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       // dwDesiredAccess
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // dwShareMode
        &sa,                                // lpSecurityAttributes
        OPEN_ALWAYS,                        // dwCreationDisposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,              // dwFlagsAndAttributes
        NULL);                              // hTemplateFile
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("CreateFile returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE errno:%d\n", GetLastError());
        myExit(1);
    }

    // write COUNT records to the file that was created using GENERIC_WRITE
    rval = 0;
    for (ii = 0; ii < COUNT; ii++) {
        sprintf_s(buf, "TEST-%d\n", pid);
        printf("WriteFile: %s", buf);
        if (!WriteFile(hFile, buf, strlen(buf), &rval, NULL)) {
            errno = GetLastError();
            if (errno == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
                printf("WriteFile returned ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER errno:%d\n", errno);
            } else {
                printf("WriteFile ERROR: returned errno:%d\n", errno);
            }
            myExit(1);
        }
        Sleep(SLEEP);
    }

    // close the file
    CloseHandle(hFile);


    // Create a file using FILE_APPEND_DATA

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    printf("CreateFile: %ws\n", filename_append);
    hFile = CreateFileW(
        filename_append,                    // lpFileName
        GENERIC_READ | FILE_APPEND_DATA,    // dwDesiredAccess
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, // dwShareMode
        &sa,                                // lpSecurityAttributes
        OPEN_ALWAYS,                        // dwCreationDisposition
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,              // dwFlagsAndAttributes
        NULL);                              // hTemplateFile
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("CreateFile returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE errno:%d\n", GetLastError());
        myExit(1);
    }

    // write COUNT records to the file that was created using FILE_APPEND_DATA
    rval = 0;
    for (ii = 0; ii < COUNT; ii++) {
        sprintf_s(buf, "TEST-%d\n", pid);
        printf("WriteFile: %s", buf);
        if (!WriteFile(hFile, buf, strlen(buf), &rval, NULL)) {
            errno = GetLastError();
            if (errno == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
                printf("WriteFile returned ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER errno:%d\n", errno);
            }
            else {
                printf("WriteFile ERROR: returned errno:%d\n", errno);
            }
            myExit(1);
        }
        Sleep(SLEEP);
    }

    // close the file
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    myExit(0);

} // main

void *myExit(int exitVal)
{
    printf("Press return to exit...\n");
    int rval = getchar();
    exit(exitVal);
} // myExit
```

Comment: GENERIC_WRITE and FILE_APPEND_DATA aren't alternatives, one to be replaced by the other. You need them both. You're writing to the file: you need GENERIC_WRITE. You're appending: you need FILE_APPEND_DATA. You're sharing writes: you need FILE_SHARE_WRITE.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for the quick response! When I use GENERIC_WRITE and FILE_APPEND_DATA with FILE_SHARE_WRITE I no longer get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER returned from WriteFile() but the file does not get appended to by both processes. Only the records from the second process show up in the file. Do you know how to get the append to work when run on a Windows Server?

Comment: Hmm. The Microsoft documentation is far from clear. Try `FILE_APPEND_DATA | FILE_GENERIC_READ`. But that only seems to be about permissions. The only sample I could find does `SetFilePointer(hAppend, 0, NULL, FILE_END)` before every write. Maybe that's what you need, or else you could use the C library functions `open()`, `write()`, and `close()`. They can certainly append.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792915/207421) about using the OVERLAPPED structure. I think this is the real solution. Seeking yourself is vulnerable to timing-window problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append data on a file in win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529314/how-to-append-data-on-a-file-in-win32)

Comment: @user207421
- The FILE_APPEND_DATA | FILE_GENERIC_READ suggestion gets a write error, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. 

- The OVERLAPPED suggestion does not write anything because WriteFile returns ERROR_IO_PENDING. I tried calling GetOverlappedResult after but it returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Next I will try:

- SetFilePointer(hAppend, 0, NULL, FILE_END) before every write.
- open()/write()/close() will work.
- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529314/how-to-append-data-on-a-file-in-win32".

I will let you know if any of these work when run on a Windows Server. Thanks!